# displaying 3rd monitor correctly in Eyefinity

Tags: eyefinity

I have a question on setting up Eyefinity on 3 monitors.   All three of my monitors display full screen when on expanded desktop.  But when Eyefinity is created, the 3rd monitor image does not fill the screen.

I have tried every setting in Eyefinity without success.   Also, I have had this set up fine before with the same video card and monitors.

- Primary display is 1920x1200, DVI.
- Extended display#2 is 1680x1050, VGA.
- Extended display #3 is 1920x1080, HDMI.
- Catalyst for each monitor is set for "scale image to full panel size" with GPU up-scaling selected.
- I am using the 14.2 Omega driver for the R9 290.

Comment: More information is required if we want to help you. Such as specs of each monitor, its native resolution and the resolutions used per screen.

Comment: Primary display is 1920x1200   Extended display#2 is 1680x1050  and extended display #3 is 1920x1080.    Catalyst for each monitor is set for "scale image to full panel size"  with gpu up-scaling selected.

Comment: Please share the information mentioned in the question so people don't waste time recommending things you have already tried.  Describe what was previously set up and what you've tried.  Are the quoted resolutions native or your current settings?

Comment: Can you still tell us your display specs? (that means brand, type and size) for all 3 monitors.